# VSTS - How do I block a release when the release to a previous environment failed?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a release definition set up in VSTS which releases from UAT through to Production.

The release is automatically created after a successful green build and the trigger to UAT is manual. I have the production trigger set up off the back of the UAT deployment with a manual approval step.

What I can't figure is - how do I stop the release being able to be deployed to Production if it has failed to deploy to UAT?

The scenario I have had today is - deployment to UAT failed due to some failing tests but the approvers can then approve the release to Production. I want to stop this to reduce risk of broken functionality going out to a Production environment.

Comment: If the answer helps you solve the problem, you can mark the answer. And it will also benefit other members who meet similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Abandon option. Once a release is abandoned it won't progress.

Comment: Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: A release gate may also help you out here (it would need to be custom built), a release can be abandoned through the REST api, an end-of-workflow on-failure task with a bit of powershell could auto abandon the release I'd guess, though I haven't tried abandoning an in-progress release.

Comment: Thanks jessehouwing, exactly the route I was going to take if there wasn't a way to do it already within VSTS.